# Facing type issue when passing array as an argument to function in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am facing some type issue along when passing array as an argument to function in react typescript. How to assign type for an array while passing as argument in function ?

I am using ramda package to perform some operation here.

Here is below code

```
import { add } from "ramda";

// score type need to define here
const calcScore = (score) => {
  const scores = {}
  const id = score[0]
  newValue = score[1]
  currentValue = scores[id] || 0; // getting issue here Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used of index type
  scores[id] = add(currentValue, newValue)
}
```

score array look like this ['ES', 200].

I am also getting one more type issue like 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type in the below code

```
import { add, propOr } from "ramda";

type actioProps = {
  ansId: string;
  ansValue: string;
}

type AppState = {
  submitted: object
}

const answer = (appState: AppState, action: actionProps) => {
  const id = prop('id')(getQues(appState, action.ansId))
  const value = props('submitted')(appState);

  //here I am getting  'undefined' cannot be used as an index type for the id
  value[id] = {
    [action.ansId]: action.ansValue
  }

  // another type issue like answers is of type unknown
  const answers = propOr({}, id)(value);
  answers[action.ansId] = action.ansValue;
}
```

In the same above code , I am getting other type issue like answers is of type unknown. Already that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that type of `prop('id')(getQues(appState, action.ansId))` can be `undefined`. Try wrapping array access into type guard if statement:

```js
if (value !== undefined) {
  value[id] = {
    [action.ansId]: action.ansValue
  }
}
```

Comment: do u have solution for other 2 issue which I have mention

Comment: For score you just need to create a tuple type: `const calcScore = (score: [string, number]) => {`. However I do not understand your `currentValue = scores[id] || 0;` line - scores is empty object so it has no keys, so it's no surprise that typechecker is angry at trying to index it. If you want no error type scores as Record like in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type

Comment: I added that for score but still I am getting issue like "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used of index type"